# Onenote Single Notebook Access

Tags: onedrive, onenote, onenote-api

We use onenote api's to access user's onenote notebooks and sync to our system.

When we do oauth for the first time, we get options like 'office.onenote_update_by_app' which allow us to create / edit pages in any of the user notebook and read only those pages.

But we need an option for user to allow us to access only 1 specific notebook. All the pages, sections created by a user directly in that notebook should also be accessible by our app. And no other notebook should be accessible in any way.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: So you initially get full access to the users notebooks, but you want to relinquish this after creating a specific notebook?

Comment: No, I do not want full access to users notebooks at any time, but full access to a specific notebook.